# Pandas groupby and keep the max length value

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame:

```
name    state   gender  region  old_ip1 old_ip2 new_ip1 new_ip2
ABC     GA      M       East    1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5     
ABC     GA      M       East                
ABC     GA      M       East                
ABC     GA      M       East                    3.4.5.6 4.5.6.7
ABC     A       M       South               
ABC     GA      M       South   5.6.7.8 6.7.8.9     
ABC     GA      M       South                   7.8.9.1 8.9.1.2
BCD     GA      M       East    9.1.2.3 1.2.3.4     
BCD     GA      M       East                    2.3.4.5 3.4.5.6
```

I need to group by the data frame by the first 4 columns, and keep the ip value. Each group has one row with old ip 1 and 2, and a different row with new ip 1 and 2. It's possible a group also contains rows without any values in old ip and new ip.

The output should be:

```
name    state   gender  region  old_ip1 old_ip2 new_ip1 new_ip2
ABC     GA      M       East    1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5 3.4.5.6 4.5.6.7 
ABC     GA      M       South   5.6.7.8 6.7.8.9 7.8.9.1 8.9.1.2
BCD     GA      M       East    9.1.2.3 1.2.3.4 2.3.4.5 3.4.5.6
```

I am thinking to concatenate all values for each group, or use max, but neither works. Here is my code so far:

```
df.groupby(['name', 'state', 'gender', 'region'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x : ';'.join(x))
df.groupby(['name', 'state', 'gender', 'region'], as_index=False).max()
```

Error msg:

```
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1, placement implies 6
```

Looking for a solution. It does not have to be concatenating.

Comment: please don't post images. Prior to the `.groupby`, can you do `df.to_dict()` and paste the code in your question?

Comment: You may be able to just do: `df.groupby(['name', 'state', 'gender', 'region'], as_index=False).max()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could do `pd.merge`

first you set index and replace empty value with NaN.

```
df = df.set_index(['name', 'state', 'gender', 'region'])
df = df.replace('', np.nan)
```

then you can do merging like this, drop empty values:

```
df_old = df[['old_ip1', 'old_ip2']].dropna()
df_new = df[['new_ip1', 'new_ip2']].dropna()

df = pd.merge(df_old, df_new, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

**Outputs**

```
                          old_ip1  old_ip2  new_ip1  new_ip2
name state gender region
ABC  GA    M      East    1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6  4.5.6.7
                  South   5.6.7.8  6.7.8.9  7.8.9.1  8.9.1.2
BCD  GA    M      East    9.1.2.3  1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max`. You just need to make sure all of the data contains strings, so I use `.fillna('0')`:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan).fillna('0')
df = df.groupby(['name', 'state', 'gender', 'region'], as_index=False).max()
df
Out[1]: 
  name state gender region  old_ip1  old_ip2  new_ip1  new_ip2
0  ABC    GA      M   East  1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6  4.5.6.7
1  ABC    GA      M  South  5.6.7.8  6.7.8.9  7.8.9.1  8.9.1.2
2  BCD    GA      M   East  9.1.2.3  1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6
```

OR, you could use `groupby` with `fill()` and `bfill()` and then `drop_duplicates()`:

```
df = df.replace('', np.nan) 
cols= ['old_ip1', 'old_ip2', 'new_ip1', 'new_ip2']
df[cols] = df.groupby(['name', 'state', 'gender', 'region']).ffill().bfill()
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df
Out[1]: 
  name state gender region  old_ip1  old_ip2  new_ip1  new_ip2
0  ABC    GA      M   East  1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6  4.5.6.7
4  ABC    GA      M  South  5.6.7.8  6.7.8.9  7.8.9.1  8.9.1.2
7  BCD    GA      M   East  9.1.2.3  1.2.3.4  2.3.4.5  3.4.5.6
```